# Scanner inside a loop - Why does it not exit loop when incorrect input is entered?

Tags: java

The code -

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
     System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
    try{
         numbers[i] = keyboardScanner.nextInt();
    }catch(InputMismatchException ex)
    {
      System.out.println("You did not enter a number!");
    }
}
```

If you enter a String, it loops till 'count'. Why does that happen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it'll loop until `count`: you caught the exception and continued the loop anyway.

You want to `break` out of your loop when you get that exception:

```
System.out.println("You did not enter a number!");
break;
```

Comment: Yes, the break will help. But, i have another question. Why not design the Java language such that the loop will not execute fully if some exception is thrown ?

Comment: @Apple Grinder: Because there might be good reasons to stay in the loop after an exception was thrown.

Comment: It is because the exception is caught, period.  ***Caught exceptions are not thrown from try-catch!!!!!***